# Does Trustpilot API have any limitation about the number of requests?

Tags: trustpilot

since trustpilot do not allow us to query just the reviews published after a specific date I will need to make loads of requests to get the products reviews.

Do you have any limit on the number of requests we can make in a minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @neisantos for your question.

Unfortunately our product reviews API doesn't support a query based on published datetime.

Fortunately for you, you don't need to worry about query limitations on the endpoint. However, we can see which apiKey is accessing our endpoints, and if necessary we can throttle or revoke the access.

BTW. Fetching all product reviews via the API will probably not affect our API that much :)